# Reorder factor in R based on values corresponding to a specific level of a "subfactor" of the original factor

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataset in R with the following structure:

**sub**    **ses**    **value**

sub1      0        .1454

sub1      1        .0857

sub2      0        .1123

sub2      1        .2345

sub3      0        .2105

sub3      1        .0665

```
df <- data.frame(sub=c("sub1","sub1","sub2","sub2","sub3","sub3"),ses=c(0,1,0,1,0,1),value=c(.1454,.0857,.1123,.2345,.2105,.0665))
```

For the purposes of plotting the change in value between session 0 and 1, I'm interested in reordering the dataset so that the order of Sub reflects the variable Value *only* for Ses == 0 in *descending* order, so you can easily visualize differences in "Baseline" (Ses == 0) values across subjects, while keeping both of each subject's values together in the data frame:

**sub**    **ses**    **value**

sub2      0        .1123

sub2      1        .2345

sub1      0        .1454

sub1      1        .0857

sub3      0        .2105

sub3      1        .0665

```
df <- data.frame(sub=c("sub2","sub2","sub1","sub1","sub3","sub3"),ses=c(0,1,0,1,0,1),value=c(.1123,.2345,.1454,.0857,.2105,.0665))
```

This has turned out to be a nontrivial solution for a relatively large dataset. I want something akin to

```
df.ordered <- df %>% group_by(sub) %>% arrange(desc(ses == 0, .by_group=TRUE))
```

but this syntax is incorrect, as you cannot specify a value of ses this way (it will just reorder by ses in this case). Much appreciation for anyone who can give me guidance on how to implement this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first extract the correct order in which you want to `arrange` the data by filtering only the 0 values and arranging them by `value`

```
library(dplyr)
correct_order <- df %>%
                  filter(ses == 0) %>%
                  arrange(value) %>%
                  pull(sub)
correct_order
#[1] "sub2" "sub1" "sub3"
```

You can then `arrange` them using `match` :

```
df %>% arrange(match(sub, correct_order), ses)
#  sub ses  value
#1 sub2   0 0.1123
#2 sub2   1 0.2345
#3 sub1   0 0.1454
#4 sub1   1 0.0857
#5 sub3   0 0.2105
#6 sub3   1 0.0665
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, this is excellent. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

We can use `arrange` on a `factor` with `levels` specified according to the custom  values we want it to order

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   dplyr::arrange(factor(sub, levels = 
               unique(sub[ses ==0][order(value[ses == 0])])))
#  sub ses  value
#1 sub2   0 0.1123
#2 sub2   1 0.2345
#3 sub1   0 0.1454
#4 sub1   1 0.0857
#5 sub3   0 0.2105
#6 sub3   1 0.0665
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! If I have a large dataset however (with ~80 subjects, each with a unique Value for sessions 0 and 1), I will need syntax that is more generalizable such that i do not have to explicitly specify the order (particularly since I will need to do this iteratively for different "Value" columns)

Comment: @user13471118 I have a doubt.  Why do you choose 'sub2' as the first element?

Comment: I didn't specify clearly (I edited now), but I want these values in descending order

Comment: @user13471118 you can check the update.  Here, we don't need to create a separate object